# Компьютер видит приложение вирусом

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp-ip

Компьютер видит мой exe файл вирусом. Код приложения

```
import socket
from time import sleep

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 40001
data1 = []


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    connected = True
    with conn:
        print('Connected by:', addr)
        f = open('file.txt', 'a+')
        while connected:
            try:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                dannye = data[4:].decode(encoding='utf-8')
                li = list(dannye.split())
                print("li:", li)
                if not data:
                    continue
                elif li[0] == '0':
                    f = open('file.txt', 'w+')
                # else:
                #     f = open('file.txt', 'a+')
                print(dannye, conn)
                f.write(dannye)
                f.write('\n')
                f.flush()
            except ConnectionError:
                connected = False
                print("connection lost... reconnecting")
                while not connected:
                    try:
                        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
                            s.listen(1)
                            conn, addr = s.accept()
                        connected = True
                        print("re-connection successful")
                    except ConnectionError:
                        sleep(2)
    
    f.close()
    print('Disconnected by:', addr)
    
    conn.close()

    s.close()
```

Можете дать совет как можно это изменить? Спасибо!

Comment: Я исправил табуляции, не не уверен, что правильно. И если вы используете `with` с каким-то объектом, то `close` ему делать не нужно (но это вы сами исправляйте).

Comment: А по сути вопроса, сейчас очень много вирусов-даунлоадеров, вы получаете что-то по сети и записываете в файл, это подозрительно с точки зрения антивирусов. Вирусы так обновления получают. Разве что прямо сказать антивирусу, чтобы внёс вашу программу в список исключений.

Comment: а как это сделать? cказать антивирусу чтоб он внес ее в исключения

Comment: а поняла, у каждого  антивируса разная инструкция, спасибо!